# Simplest/Most Efficient Way to create a Definition List in channel fields

Tags: channel-entries, .html

I want to create a definition list and it's overkill to create a whole separate channel for this.

Ideally in my channel entry there would be a field to create a definition list.

What's the best way to input the data?

```
<dl>
  <dt>Client:</dt>
  <dd><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">Company name</a></dd>
  <dt>Creative Director:</dt>
  <dd><a href="http://personalsite.com" target="_blank">Team Member</a></dd>
  <dt>Developers:</dt>
  <dd><a href="http://http://companysite.com" target="_blank">Company</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. Does the definition list need to be re-usable? Generally speaking, a definition list would be entered just as you did above. Your only concerns would be to make sure the field is a text field or text_area, with format set to none. If you are using a WYSIWYG field, then you'd need to enter 'source' view.

Comment: I need to make it client friendly so they could enter in a series of fields which would then become dd & dt

Answer (score 2):

Matrix is an excellent option if you can put this content inline in a given entry and not need to re-use it.

If you need to, for example, add a filter down the line with only those entries that have client company of ABC Company, for example, it may be ever so slightly harder to achieve without having that content at the entries level (without having to get into some custom queries, anyway) - so if setup as entries, you could then use a relationship field (or a Playa relationship field if multiples of any of your assignments would need it).

Another option would be categories, but also not quite as user friendly on the admin end.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use Matrix. Perfect for what I need. So versatile.

Answer (score 0):

[P&T List](http://pixelandtonic.com/divebar) from Pixel and Tonic is also great for doing something like this if you have fixed Definition Terms but need your user to be able to add multiple Definition Descriptions. Just define a new channel field for each DT/DD combo. It's nice and light weight and also free.